# Remove sub-domains from list of domains using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings like this:

```
a@domain.com
b@sub.domain.com
c@sub.sub.domain.com
d@sub.domain2.com
```

I want to remove the subdomains and only leave the `domain.com`, `domain2.com`, etc..

What I have tried so far but with no success:

```
string[] campusCup(string[] emails)
{
    var emailList = emails.Select(x => x.Split('@').Last())
                        .Distinct()
                        .Select(x => x.Where(y => x.Split('.').Length > 2).Select(z => x.Split('.').Reverse().Take(2).Reverse()))
                        .Select(x => x)
                        .Distinct();

    return emailList.ToArray();
}
```

Any help solving the task or explanation of what I am doing wrong and how can I solve it is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you literally only want "domain.com" and "domain2.com", or do you just want any 2nd-level domains? For example, would "someDomain.org", be valid?

Comment: Yes, 2-nd level domains should be included as well. "someDomain.org" would be valid. So would "mit.edu.ru".

Comment: string.Join(".", x.Split('.').Reverse().Take(2).Reverse())

Comment: So you're only excluding sub domains if the main domain is already in the list?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by that @DavidG. But my goal is to get a list of main domains excluded from their subdomains. Based on the list I gave in the first post, I need to get "domain.com" and "domain2.com" only.

Comment: What should be the answer if your input is `a@mit.edu.ru`?

Comment: But why is `sub.domain2.com` invalid and `mit.edu.ru` valid? What are your rules for that? What if you had `x@school.ac.uk` and `y@department.school.ac.uk`?

Comment: You're right. I went through the task again and it appears that I only need to get the last 2 parts of the domain. So, if the input is a@mit.edu.ru, it would need to output `edu.ru` only.

Comment: So, what about `bob@bbc.co.uk`? If you get the last 2 parts, that's not a valid domain.

Comment: You are right, it's not. But this is just a task to learn more about linq. Not an actual real life example. So I am guessing if I had to look for valid domains there would be another more complex method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first use [`MailAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the host, then some string methods to get only the last two:

```
string[] domains = emails
 .Select(e => new MailAddress(e).Host.Split('.'))
 .Select(arr => String.Join(".", arr.Skip(arr.Length - 2)))
 .Distinct()
 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me given your data set:

```
var domains = emails.Select(e => e.Split('@')[1]).Select(d =>
{
    var parts = d.Split('.');
    return string.Join(".", parts.Skip(parts.Length - 2));
}).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to learn about LINQ, as you mention in the comments of your question, here is another fun option:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"[a-z0-9\.]+@[a-z0-9\.]*?(?<domain>[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+)$");   
var secondLevelDomains = domains.SelectMany(domainName => reg.Matches(domainName).Cast<Match>()
                                                             .Select(m => m.Groups["domain"])
                                                             .Select(m => m.Value))
                                                             .Distinct();
```

It uses matching groups in regular expressions to parse the domain names, and several of the more interesting LINQ functions, like `Cast` (for converting older collections in to LINQ friendly enumerables), `SelectMany` (to merge enumerable properties of multiple items), and `Distinct` (to return only unique entries).

This is probably not the *ideal* way to do this in a real application, but it exposes a lot of LINQ functionality for learning purposes.